# Selectively prevent Wordpress from generating additional image sizes on upload

Tags: php, wordpress, file-upload

I am getting some images from clients via a front-end form and uploading those images to the Media Gallery programmatically. The code works fine and uploads the images as intended.

But in the wp-uploads folder it creates copies of these images for all the sizes. I **do not** want WP to do that **only** when images are uploaded via this form because just the original image file that the client uploads is sufficient for my need. Could someone please guide me in the right direction? Thank you.

Comment: How is this form built?

Comment: @MosheGross via a custom plugin from the ground-up..

Comment: You might be able to by adding `add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', '__return_empty_array');` on your upload page only

Comment: @MosheGross LEGEND! It works! Please submit this as an answer so that I accept it. And also, please upvote my question if you like. I am a little below 50 reputation to comment on answers so I find it difficult to reply to my answerers. Thanks gain, man :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to a community member, **Moshe Gross**, the filter to target is

```
add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', '__return_empty_array');
```

Answer (score 1):

Wordpress makes different size images for different uses within the blog, for example, when showing a list of posts it might use a thumbnail next to the article title and so on. You can disable those with 0 values in the resize settings.

1: Login To Your WP Dashboard.
2: Go to Settings and then, Media.
3: Here you will find 3 various image sizes: thumbnail, medium, large.
4: Decide which image sizes you won't be using and then set those sizes to 0. Update and save your new settings.

Please don't forget to award the final answer to whoever helps. So others can see the solution.

Comment: I don't want to turn-off that functionality totally. Only when images are uploaded through this form.

Comment: And how is the form made. With a plugin or? You don't mention, other than "form".

Comment: I'm very sorry if you needed this detail. But I found out that the filter to target is `add_filter('intermediate_image_sizes_advanced', '__return_empty_array');`. :)